# Why does Youtube shows 301+ views?

Tags: youtube

I am just curious about why does Youtube shows 301+ views. I think there must be some logic behind that. What it could be?

I have seen exact count of views lesser than 300 views as well as having count in several thousands and millions.

Comment: I really do not understand why people are giving negative points to the question I have without giving any explanation. I had some curiosity so I asked, your negative marks doesn't help me to get my answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself, it is no longer the case and it's been resolved.

So whenever a new video used to upload it receives many likes including from bots. So to verify the legitimacy of likes YouTube counter used to stop after 300 likes to verify sources of likes.

Official release: https://mobile.twitter.com/YTCreators/status/628958720953819136

Answer (score 1):

It can stay stuck for a while. This is a control procedure for preventing the use of bots, any video getting more than 301 views in a short period gets verified in terms of source of traffic. However views are still getting counted (logged) in the back-end and will appear when YouTube will unlock the view counts.

Comment: Sound convincing. Do you have any url to share on this?